# Amazon S3API is not returning next unique records even token mentioned

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am using `aws s3api` like below:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket bucket --prefix main/content/  --starting-token eyJNYXJrZXIiOiAiZXlKTllYSnJaWE  --max-items 2  --page-size 10
```

yet I see dups are being returned. what to pass to get the next `2` records?

Comment: The response for this command should have returned a new token. You should use it to get the next set of records.

Comment: @KrishnaKumarR I did not get you. It *does* return token but previous one hence fetch duplicate records

Comment: The problem is that you are specifying different numbers in `--max-items` and `--page-size` parameters in your command. As per AWS: A service may not return items in the same order each time you call. If you specify a next token in the middle of a page, you may see different results that you expect. To prevent this, use the same number for --page-size and --max-items, to sync the CLI's pagination with the service's. You can also retrieve the whole list and perform any necessary parsing operations locally

Comment: @KrishnaKumarR pulling entire list is costly, consder TBs of data. I am already setting both page size and max items yet same token is returning.

Comment: What the document is saying is that: set your max items and page size to the same number. In your case, set them both to 2.

Comment: @KrishnaKumarR Oh OK.. Will try it and let you know.. Assuming then I will always have a unique NextToken and files?

Comment: @KrishnaKumarR seems it worked.. by setting both max items and page size to same it returns unique files now. Pls make it as an answer so I accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are specifying different numbers in --max-items and --page-size parameters in your command. As per AWS: A service may not return items in the same order each time you call. If you specify a next token in the middle of a page, you may see different results that you expect. To prevent this, use the same number for --page-size and --max-items, to sync the CLI's pagination with the service's. You can also retrieve the whole list and perform any necessary parsing operations locally.

What this means is that: set your max items and page size to the same number. In your case, set them both to 2.

AWS documentation that explains this can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/pagination.html).